# UWP: is there a method to close a currently open folder?

Tags: c#, uwp

I was able to find method to open/launch a folder:

```
await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder);
```

But now couldn't find a method to close it. Does it even exist? Thanks.

Comment: You could share some more code ..

Comment: A 'folder' here is a Windows.Storage.StorageFolder. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227230]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchfolderasync.aspx) the LaunchFolderAsync method will open the given folder in File Explorer.

So the close operation does not make sense in this context and does not exist because you cannot close other applications (nor should you) from your app.

If what you expect is to show the contents of the folder in File Explorer, you should be fine using the code you have and you don't have to worry about closing the folder.